# How to sum multiple objects together

Tags: c#, object

Lets say I have three objects

```
object o1, o2, o3
```

These objects have the values of

```
o1 = 1

o2 = 2

o3 = 3
```

For simplicity sake

Now I would like to add these objects together to get a sum of 6 but the `+` operator cannot be used with objects. What ways can these objects be summed up without extensively converting them?

The reason for using objects rather than `int` etc, is due to using a `DataTable` that gets populated by a SQL query. I then take a value from that `DataTable` and assign it to `o1` as an example.

Comment: get the value from the datatable as an int.  Cast it.

Comment: Can you modify the sql query to count those values using such a query and then just convert the value to an `int`?

Comment: @Jonesopolis I'd rather cast the object to an int because before I need it to be an int I use it as an object. How can I convert object to an int validly?

Comment: It looks like I will just have to `int total = Convert.ToInt32(o1) + Convert.ToInt32(o2)...` to get my desired result.

Comment: Why do you like the `Convert` class so much?  If you know the object contains an integer, just cast it as an integer.  `int total = (int) o1 + (int) o2;`

Comment: @MattJohnson because casting like that did not work in my program with the error of "Specified cast is not valid" due to Invalid Cast Exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overload the plus operator if you actually make your own object type. I suspect there are other ways for you to do this, for example:

> I then take a value from that DataTable and assign it to o1 as an example.

You could assign it to an `int` at that time. But if you really want to use some object, because you need to create more behavior in the future, on that object type you would:q

```
    // overload operator +
    public static YourObject operator +(YourObject a, YourObject b)
    {
        return new YourObject(a.theValuePropertyInt + b.theValuePropertyInt);
    }
```

But you are not going to be able to sum up types of C#'s `Object` because it does not overload the + operator.

Fundamentally you are trying to use object specific behavior (integer math) without telling the compiler you want int behaviors.

Ultimately, ask if this is just an `int`, or some other type. If it is really just an `int`, cast as you extract.

Answer (score 1):

Following should give you the answer, but ideally it would be better for you keep int type intact from db using a DataReader.

```
public int SumMyObjects(List<object> objs)
{
   int sum =0;
   foreach(var obj in objs)
   {
      try
      {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(obj);
      }
      catch
      {
         // obj wasn't a valid int
      }
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: I would be weary of using Convert.ToInt32. What if `object s = (char)'a';` then this would work, but would be incorrect. When would this actually throw? When `sum` is too large? I think you'd want to do `int.TryParse(s?.ToString(), out var result)` and if that is true then add it to sum. It should be fine in this case because he's pulling from a source that as int by default, but in general I wouldn't do this.